# Does 'whose workmanship they are' violate parallelism? (1690 UK)

Tags: parallelism, philosophy, seventeenth-century-english

> [Source:](http://www.constitution.org/jl/2ndtr02.htm) Sec 6, *The Second Treatise of Civil Government*, 1690, by John Locke
>
> ...for `men` being all the workmanship of one omnipotent, and infinitely wise maker; all the servants of one sovereign master, sent into the world by his order, and about his business; they are his property, **whose workmanship they are**, made to last during his, not one another's pleasure: ...

The bolded confuses me because it seems to violate parallelism. Am I right that:
1. **whose** is a relative pronoun and means 'of whom'. Then 'whom' is an objective pronoun referring to 'one sovereign master' (ie some God)?
2. **they** = `men` ?

3. If I'm right about 1 and 2, then why did Locke not simply write:
**they are his workmanship**?
Is there any  purpose or significance to this syntax for philosophy?

Footnote: I encountered this excerpt at [the 5 mins 4 s juncture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MGyygiXMzRk)  of *Justice: What's The Right Thing To Do?*, Episode 04: "THIS LAND IS MY LAND"

Comment: Not “some” god, but God himself.  This seems perfectly clear.  It was written this way because that’s how they wrote back then.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that *they* refers to "men" and that *whose* refers to "his" (that is, God's).  But it it is not a parallel structure; the bolded phrase is a relative clause modifying *they*.  I presume that Locke moved the clause away from the referent in order to highlight the primary relationship that he wanted to express ("men are God's property"); but the clause is there to establish or reinforce a clear reason *why* men are to be considered God's property.

Thus your point 3 is an invalid interpretation of the sentence.  To rephrase it in more modern language:

> *[Just as any ordinary thing belongs by default to the person who made it,]* men are the property of the God who made them, and they should live as long as God wills it, rather than as long as some other man wills.

Comment: Important though off-topic point: it is not that human lives should last as long as God rather than man wishes, it is that in fact they do.